# Movilizer - Eclipse doesn't find class 'OutlineLabelProvider'

Tags: java, eclipse, movilizer

I installed the movilizer plug-in, but whenever I try to make a movelet, I get the same error:

*Could not initialize class*
*com.movilizer.eclipse.editor.outline.OutlineLabelProvider*

```
Thread=Thread[ModalContext,6,main]
at com.movilitas.jaxbframework.dataaccess.jaxb.AbstractJaxbDAL.parseXML(AbstractJaxbDAL.java:162)
at com.movilizer.eclipse.editor.actions.MovilizerRequestEditorActionExecuteDelegate$1.run(MovilizerRequestEditorActionExecuteDelegate.java:169)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: No unmarshaller for element "{http://movilitas.com/movilizer/v15}MovilizerRequest" (line 3, col 71)
at org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext.unmarshalElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:2754)
at org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext.unmarshalDocument(UnmarshallingContext.java:2914)
at com.movilitas.jaxbframework.dataaccess.jaxb.AbstractJaxbDAL.parseXML(AbstractJaxbDAL.java:157)
... 2 more
```

Comment: Please provide stack-trace of error so then people can help to find out

Comment: It will help a lot to understand what Eclipse version exactly you are using. Same goes for the plugin version. Please add that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Eclipse Neon, use the https://devtools.movilizer.com/eclipseUpdateSite46 update site.

For older Eclipse versions, use the https://devtools.movilizer.com/eclipseUpdateSiteDev update site.

If installation from the correctly corresponding update site does not solve the problem, you work around the problem by closing the Outline view in Eclipse. 
https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcoutline.htm

Comment: I was using eclipse neon, so using the [link](https://devtools.movilizer.com/eclipseUpdateSite46) solved it. Thank you!